# WPF Speed Load Time of Expanding a Specific TreeView Element

Tags: wpf, optimization, treeview

I have been trying to find out specific ways of improving the load times of a treeview element that contains 1500 flat nodes. At the moment it takes over 15 seconds to expand a single node.

I have tried the suggestions regarding virtualisation but its my understanding that virtualisation basically avoids loading and rendering elements that cannot be seen. Correct?

If so, what happens when you expand an element where there are 1500 items within that single expansion, does it not then need to load those 1500 items?

It seems obviously, if I split up my TreeView so that each time 10 elements were added, it added another folder. So you couldn't view the whole treeview at once. This is NOT really an option for me.

So is there a way of possibly background loading the tree element add, so that I can display the treeview even while its loading items?

This is the only solution I can think of but I have yet to come across a way of being able to update the UI and not be blocking at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualization is the logical way to go.

Math is your friend here: 
Let's, for the sake of argument, assume that 1 node takes up an insanely small 5 vertical pixels. A screen with a height of 7500 pixels would be able to show all 1500 nodes.

Cutting the number in half to 750 nodes would still require a height of 3750 pixels.

If we take a more reasonable height for one node, I think the default is 19, a decent 4K monitor would be able to show around 200 of them.

I'm currently running on a 1920x1200 monitor, with scaling at 100% (strangely called "smaller"). Explorer, with the ribbon collapsed, shows me 43 items. 2000 pixels would give me around 73 items in view. And the items in Explorer are pretty much as small as I would want them to be without going blind.

Bottom line: You're unlikely to run in to the problems with virtualization.

Comment: I now agree - I put together a test app, virtualisation worked, so I pulled out bits of my larger application until the virtualisation actually functioned as I expected and discovered it was a rouge scrollviewer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming across this question. Ensure you haven't wrapped (or even have a scrollviewer) in the same grid as your treeview.

It completely disables virtualisation without warning.